# Bind Ex-mode command in Evil

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I am trying to bind `CTRL-B` to perform the Evil command `:buffers`. The reason I am doing this is because I want to scroll through the open buffers with `j` and `k` and then press `<RET>` to make the selection.

What I tried was adding the following code to my configuration file:

```
;; Switch Evil-mode buffers
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-B") ":buffers")
```

The result of reloading this configuration (`:eval-buffer`) and then pressing `CTRL-B` leads to:

> After 0 kbd macro iterations: Can't find "

How can we bind to an Ex-mode command?

Comment: By the way: there's probably a typo you need to fix: there is no `evil-mode-map`.  Do you mean `evil-normal-state-map` or something along those lines?

Comment: Dan that's right. Thanks. :) I wanted to bind to every mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`evil` source](https://github.com/emacsmirror/evil/blob/cd005aa50ab056492752c319b5105c38c79c2fd0/evil-maps.el#L442), we can see:

```el
(evil-ex-define-cmd "buffers" 'buffer-menu)
```

In this case, I'd recommend binding to the command directly, instead of going through the `ex` interface.

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-B") #'buffer-menu)
```

However, if you find that you absolutely must, you can use a keyboard macro:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-B") (kbd ":buffers"))
```

Comment: Just a note: you don't actually need to consult the source to find the functions for `ex` commands: there is an `evil-ex-commands` alist. eg. `(cdr (assoc "buffers" evil-ex-commands))` will return the function corresponding to ":buffers".